# Windows - Get ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT on local site

Tags: windows, apache, google-chrome, ssl-certificate, ampps

I am working on Windows 10, using Ampps. I have created a domain (tps.local) using Ampps Panel with support to SSL. I see it creates a cert, but when I work from Chrome I get Get ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT error.

I have tried:

1. Importing certificate as trusted.
2. Setting url on Windows trusted sites list.
3. Changing flag in Chrome to allow unsecure localhost certificate
4. Setting time adjustment to automatic
5. Cleared SSL cache.
6. After every change I have restarted chrome using chrome://restart

Do I have to create a new certificate? I have installed OpenSSL for Windows, but I am not sure (if necessary) how to proceed since Ampps already created a cert.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed problem by self-signing certificate [here](https://zerossl.com/free-ssl/#self): 
I've entered "***somesite.local 192.168.0.2***".
Then add domain in ampps panel with SSL checkbox on.

Then replace `apache\conf\ssl_key\YOURDOMAIN.key` and `apache\conf\ssl_crt\YOURDOMAIN.crt` with those you got from [zerossl](https://zerossl.com/free-ssl/#self).

> **Note:** Don't forget to restart Apache

Comment: I searched high and low for solution that would work: and this did. Thank you so much for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a solution, but a workaround:

Switch to Firefox, because you can easily ignore the warning there (at least for now - Firefox 58).